Is there a more elegant way to change the structure of my dictionary data?
I made this function because I needed to get data in a different order. It works, but I'm wondering if there is a better way.
def transform_data(self, data):
    """
    before: data[subject][period][zodiak] = content
    after : data[zodiak][period][subject] = content
    """

    result = {}
    for subject, subject_data in data.items():
        for period, period_data in subject_data.items():
            for zodiak, content in period_data.items():

                if zodiak not in result:
                    result[zodiak] = {}
                if period not in result[zodiak]:
                    result[zodiak][period] = {}
                if subject not in result[zodiak][period]:
                    result[zodiak][period][subject] = {}

                result[zodiak][period][subject] = content

    return result


Have a look at defaultdict

The last if is unnecessary. If the subject is not in the dictionary, result[zodiak][period][subject] = content will put it there. No need to set that to an empty map first.

I would only do result.setdefault(zodiak, {}).setdefault([period, {})[subject] = content but the code is perfect.

@KamilCuk wouldn't that retain the default in subsequent usage? You only want this default while building the result; you don't want, for example, transform_data(data)["nonexistent_key"][period][subject] to return {}.

wouldn't that retain the default in subsequent usage? no

@KamilCuk thanks, you're right, I was confusing setdefault with defaultdict.
